# Sliding-Doors Child Theme

Tags: child-theme, author-template

I'm trying to make a child theme for Sliding-Doors, a Wordpress site. I'm following all the right steps but the child theme is not showing up on my admin panel to activate it. Is it because I am using an index.html to show a "coming soon" page while I am still building the WP site?

If you type http://www.examplesite.com, you'd get the "coming soon" page. If you type http://examplesite.myname.com/php, you'd see the Sliding-Doors WP site I'm working on. Guess I'm not sure what to put in after Theme "URI" and "Author URI". I've tried several combinations but to no avail. Any help?
Thanks.

(here's the style.css)

```
/*
Theme Name: Sliding Door Child
Theme URI:
Description: Child Theme for Sliding Door
Author: Your name!
Author URI:
Template: sliding-door
Version: 0.1
*/

@import url("../sliding-door/style.css");
@import url("../sliding-door/dark.css");
@import url("../sliding-door/light.css");
@import url("../sliding-door/imagemenu/imageMenu.css");

/* Place new css code below here */
```

Answer (score 1):

From [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#The_required_style.css_file), the Template: bit needs to be the name of the **directory** for the parent theme; you have the nice name of the theme instead.

Comment: I know the Template is case-sensitive and went back and changed it appropriately but it still does not work. I also left out the URI's as they are optional. Any thoughts?

Comment: You must use the name of the parent theme's folder, not the name of the parent theme. Is the name of the parent theme's folder "Sliding Door" or "sliding-door"? (NB: with a minus sign between the words)

Comment: Yes. It's actually "sliding-door". I tried that and it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you edit your question so that I can see that please? It currently still says "Sliding Door".

Comment: I corrected the above code which can also be found here:http://mac-host.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1869&sid=e7bb26b217b78d1716e2896243281b10. Thanks for all of your help, by the way.

Comment: Actually, just click on the link. I can't seem to get the full code in there.

Comment: Any other files in your child theme folder? (Try to keep it minimal until you've got that child theme listed in the admin)

Comment: No. Just the one style.css file everybody says to make for the child theme.

Comment: Odd. Sorry, but without more information (practically, poking at the site), I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Solved it! I entered all the folders, files, and etc... directly into my host and did not use an FTP. I don't know why it wasn't working that way, it should, but it works this way.